# How to capitalize the first letter while making or maintaining the other characters in lowercase using prompt in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a code here but I don't understand how to convert it. The prompt should be asking your name but I need to make the first letter uppercase. The characters should be on lowercase.

```js
var myName = "Rafael";

var messge = "Hello";

var yourName = prompt("What is your name? ");

console.log("My name is " + myName + ", " + messge + " " + yourName + "." );
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript

Comment: https://flexiple.com/javascript/javascript-capitalize-first-letter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myName = "Rafael";

var messge = "Hello";

var yourName = prompt("What is your name? ");

yourName = yourName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + yourName.slice(1).toLowerCase();

console.log("My name is " + myName + ", " + messge + " " + yourName + "." );
```

Try this.

Comment: Not that one, there is a prompt that would ask for your name. The name you will put is what I want to make the first letter uppercase while the rests are lowercase.

Comment: The First letter works but I still need the rest of the other characters in lowercase. Sorry about this, I'm so new to programming

Comment: yourName = yourName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + yourName.slice(1).toLowerCase();

Comment: @JakePacholski you dont need .toLowerCase(); at the end, if you press at Run code snippet at my answer and then type in lets say `jake` at the end you will get `Hello Jake`

Comment: Ok thanks btw, really appreciate it. I was actually required to maintain the second and other characters in lowercase. For example, If I type "JAKE.", the result is all capitalized, it won't be "Jake." The code worked somehow.

Comment: @JakePacholski yeah in that case `.toLowerCase()` is needed at the end, also all good its a pleasure to help others. Ill update my answer and add that there.